# Área de Perguntas com Tempo

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação que deverá disponibilizar um ambiente onde as seguintes funções são executadas:

**Administrador**
- Cadastra perguntas
- Edita usuário
- Visualiza respostas
- Visualiza provas
- Inseri nota

**Usuario**
- Se cadastra
- Preenche prova

Nesse ambiente o tempo será cronometrado a base do tempo de inicio da prova que será relacionado com o tempo preenchido pelo administrador no cadastro de provas. 
Pensei em validar o tempo por jQuery apenas inserindo no banco o horário inicial da prova e comparando independente do usuário fechar ou não o navegador. Como trabalharei com ajax, não me preocuparei com o usuário desabilitar ou não o javascript. Cada pergunta estará em uma tela que será disponibilizada via ajax e se ele fechar o navegador e reabrir, voltara a responder na que parou (sem trazer o que ele preencheu na mesma).

Criei os seguintes dominios:

Aluno

```
public class Bolsa_Aluno
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Nome deve ser preenchido")]
        public string Nome { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Email deve ser preenchido")]
        [RegularExpression(@"^([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+)@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.)|(([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+\.)+))([a-zA-Z]{2,4}|[0-9]{1,3})(\]?)$", ErrorMessage = "E-mail inválido")]
        public string Email { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "CPF deve ser preenchido")]
        [StringLength(11, ErrorMessage = "Digite apenas 11 números")]
        public string CPF { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Telefone deve ser preenchido")]
        [StringLength(15, ErrorMessage = "Digite no máximo 15 caracteres")]
        public string Telefone { get; set; }

        public string Curso { get; set; }

        public virtual int AlunoProvaID { get; set; }
        public virtual Bolsa_AlunoProva AlunoProva { get; set; }
    }
```

AlunoProva

```
public class Bolsa_AlunoProva
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public int Nota { get; set; }
        public DateTime DataInicial { get; set; }
        public DateTime DataFinal { get; set; }

        public virtual int AlunoID { get; set; }
        public virtual Bolsa_Aluno Aluno { get; set; }

        public virtual int ProvaID { get; set; }
        public virtual Bolsa_Prova Prova { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Bolsa_AlunoResposta> AlunoResposta { get; set; }
    }
```

AlunoResposta

```
public class Bolsa_AlunoResposta
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Resposta { get; set; }

        public virtual int AlunoProvaID { get; set; }
        public virtual Bolsa_AlunoProva AlunoProva { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Bolsa_Pergunta> Pergunta { get; set; }
    }
```

Pergunta

```
public class Bolsa_Pergunta
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Pergunta deve ser preenchido")]
        public string Pergunta { get; set; }

        public virtual int AlunoProvaID { get; set; }
        public virtual Bolsa_AlunoProva AlunoProva { get; set; }

        public virtual int AlunoRespostaID { get; set; }
        public virtual Bolsa_AlunoResposta AlunoResposta { get; set; }
    }
```

Prova

```
public class Bolsa_Prova
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Tempo deve ser preenchido em minutos")]
        public int Tempo { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Quantidade de Perguntas deve ser preenchido")]
        public int QuantidadePerguntas { get; set; }

        public string Nome { get; set; }
        public string Bandeira { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Bolsa_Pergunta> Pergunta { get; set; }
    }
```

Minha dúvida é a seguinte. Essa é a melhor pratica de validação e armazenamento contando que eu não preciso me preocupar extremamente com segurança?

É uma má prática salvar cada resposta individualmente no banco para "manter a sessão" se caso o usuário fechar o navegador?

Ao executar migration (trabalho com code-first), me deparei com o seguinte erro de relacionamento:

> Unable to determine the principal end of an association between the
>   types 'Dominio.Bolsa_AlunoProva' and 'Dominio.Bolsa_Aluno'. The
>   principal end of this association must be explicitly configured using
>   either the relationship fluent API or data annotations.

Seria correto aplicar como solução a tag `[Required]` em `Bolsa_AlunoProva` no item `public virtual Bolsa_Prova Prova { get; set; }` ?

Comment: Nunca tinha visto o termo *tag* para o que oficialmente é chamado de atributo. Não deixa de ser uma mesmo :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Essa é a melhor pratica de validação e armazenamento contando que eu não preciso me preocupar extremamente com segurança?

O aspecto de segurança está mais ligado ao *Controller* do que ao *Model* em si, portanto ao que foi indicado, não há necessariamente problemas de segurança no seu *Model*.

## É uma má prática salvar cada resposta individualmente no banco para "manter a sessão" se caso o usuário fechar o navegador?

Não, é o recomendado. Aliás, em questão de comprovação documental, seria o ideal porque você pode usar um carimbo de tempo do servidor pra dizer exatamente em que dia e hora a resposta foi recebida.

## Ao executar migration (trabalho com code-first), me deparei com o seguinte erro de relacionamento...

O erro acontece porque você permite que um Aluno tenha apenas uma prova. Mude para o seguinte:

```
    // Retire esse ID
    // public virtual int AlunoProvaID { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Bolsa_AlunoProva> AlunoProvas { get; set; }
```

Mesmo que o Aluno só possa ter uma prova, a associação 1 pra 1 estrita está fazendo o Entity Framework se perder porque ele não tem como determinar direito as chaves estrangeiras. Seria algo como:

```
create table Aluno (
    ID int primary key, 
    AlunoProvaID int foreign key references AlunoProva (ID)
)

create table AlunoProva (
    ID int primary key, 
    AlunoID int foreign key references Aluno (ID)
)
```

## Seria correto aplicar como solução a tag `[Required]` em `Bolsa_AlunoProva` no item `public virtual Bolsa_Prova Prova { get; set; }` ?

Isso não resolve o problema (ver item anterior).